# Multiple language support does not work for just one string value Why?

Tags: android, string, textview, multilingual

I have an app which supports multiple languages 'English' and 'Turkish'. But when I change phone language from English to Turkish all screens language changes but just one screens textview does not change I have searched but didn't find a solution. Here is my structure to support languages while changing phone language:

[image]

Here is strings.xml for English:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">KYC SDK App</string>
    <string name="capture_button_alt">Capture</string>
    <string name="switch_camera_button_alt">Switch camera</string>
    <string name="gallery_button_alt">Gallery</string>
    <string name="back_button_alt">Back</string>
    <string name="share_button_alt">Share</string>
    <string name="share_hint">Share using</string>
    <string name="capture_mode_camera">Camera</string>
    <string name="capture_mode_hdr">HDR</string>
    <string name="capture_mode_night">Night</string>
    <string name="delete_button_alt">Delete</string>
    <string name="delete_dialog">Delete current photo?</string>
    <string name="delete_title">Confirm</string>
    <string name="timer">00:30</string>
    <string name="blink_description">Blink your eyes!</string>
    <string name="keep_card_description">Keep going to hold the card!</string>
</resources>
```

Here is the strings.xml for Turkish:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">KYC SDK App</string>
    <string name="capture_button_alt">Çek</string>
    <string name="switch_camera_button_alt">Kamerayı Çevir</string>
    <string name="gallery_button_alt">Galeri</string>
    <string name="back_button_alt">Geri</string>
    <string name="share_button_alt">Paylaş</string>
    <string name="share_hint">Paylaş</string>
    <string name="capture_mode_camera">Kamera</string>
    <string name="capture_mode_hdr">HDR</string>
    <string name="capture_mode_night">Gece</string>
    <string name="delete_button_alt">Sil</string>
    <string name="delete_dialog">Fotoğraf Silinsin mi?</string>
    <string name="delete_title">Onayla</string>
    <string name="timer">00:30</string>
    <string name="blink_description">Gözünüzü kırpın!</string>
    <string name="keep_card_description">Kartı tutmaya devam edin!</string>

</resources>
```

Here is where I use the string named "keep_card_description" in textview:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/camera_mrz_textView_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="@string/keep_card_description"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This is the structure of my multiple language support. When I change the language English to Turkish the strings are changing except one. Why just one string does not change?

Comment: hi, can you share the content of your strings in both values and values-tr folders?

Comment: I have edited as you suggested

Comment: where is the string that does not change?

Comment: last string name="keep_card_description"

Comment: Can you also share your layout file which you use that string?

Comment: I have added the textview where I use this string named "@string/keep_card_description"

Comment: i've just tried yours strings and it works just fine. may be you need to clean and rebuild your app

Answer (score 0):

As you said changing the language works for all strings except one string so I'll assume that the code you use to change the language is working well and you are setting local well too.
but you didn't explain if you were using the string in XML file or you are setting it programmatically.

But I'll tell one thing about changing the language that application context once created will not be recreated so the application context will be using the language were set when the app started.

so if you were setting the string programmatically make sure you are using the activity context and not application context and also make sure that the activity is recreated after the language changed because maybe you are changing the language from settings activity but you click the back button and find that language didn't change as the context didn't change so you need to recreate the activity, in such case I recommend you to finish affinity and start first or splash activity so you make sure all activities will be created with the new language